# Plotly not displaying the y zero line

Tags: python, layout, plotly

when plotting data using plotly the y-zero line is not shown in the grid (it is blank), creating a weird blank space.

I've tried to modify the grid parameters so y-zero and x-zero lines are always displayed, but it hasn't work. I attach the function that plots the data. See the image and how for y=0 there is no grey line:
[example of the behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH0UM.png)

```
def plot_dictionary_lines(data_dict, title, colors, dtick_y, y_title):
    tilt_values = list(data_dict.keys())
    orientation_values = list(data_dict[tilt_values[0]].keys())
    
    fig = go.Figure()
    
    for i,tilt in enumerate(tilt_values):
        tilt_data = data_dict[tilt]
        y_values = []
        for orientation in orientation_values:
            y_values.append(tilt_data[orientation])
        
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=orientation_values, y=y_values, mode='lines', name=tilt,  line=dict(color=colors[i])))
    
    fig.update_layout(title=title, xaxis_title='Orientation')
    fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(title=y_title, dtick=dtick_y, minor=dict(ticks="inside", showgrid=True)))
    fig.update_layout(title=title, title_font_size=12, title_x=0.5, margin=dict(l=5, r=5, t=30, b=5))
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, plot_bgcolor= 'white' )
    fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, mirror=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', gridcolor='grey', gridwidth=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, mirror=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', gridcolor='grey', gridwidth=1)
    fig.update_layout(legend_title_text='Tilt (deg)')
    fig.show()
```

Data to reproduce the plot:

```
data_dict = {'20': {'0': -29.993976613550426,
  '90': -9.982751500722712,
  '180': 0.0,
  '270': -16.409959148158066},
 '40': {'0': -51.454747907503716,
  '90': -13.263266344556737,
  '180': 0.0,
  '270': -23.372002876678337},
 '60': {'0': -60.76495332385845,
  '90': -13.362989512932888,
  '180': 0.0,
  '270': -25.197913842540597}}

title = "Solar production sold entirely, respect south"

color_codes = { 
    "10colors": [
        '#cce542', '#98d956', '#66cb69', '#2fba79', '#00a884',
        '#009589', '#008286', '#006e7d', '#185b6d', '#2a4858']
    }

colors = color_codes["10colors"]

d_ticky = 5

y_title = "%"
```

Comment: HI marcelsa! Welcome to StackOverflow ‍. It seems like your example requires a bit of data to get up and running. Would you be able to include some data in your question? Thanks!

Comment: More info on what makes a good question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @Mark, I added the data to reproduce the plot. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: [this is what it shows for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hke5O.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That took me forever.

Apparently the zero line does NOT follow the grid color. It has separate properties, zerolinecolor and zerolinewidth.
Yours is currently white on a white background. Change it like this (or another color):

fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(zerolinecolor='black'))